# Create order : how to set price?

Tags: 8, commerce

In my module, on a `cron_job` function I need to create an order with specific `order_item` price.
Here is my code :

```
        switch ($role[1]) {
            case 'biocoop':
                $role_price = $produit->get('field_prix_biocoop');
                break;
            case 'montagne':
                $role_price = $produit->get('field_prix_montagne');

                break;
            case 'vente_directe':
                $role_price = $produit->get('field_prix_vd');
                break;
              /* default:
              $role_price = $produit->getPrice();
              break; */
        }     

        $order_item = \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderItem::create([
            'type' => 'default',
            'purchased_entity' => $produit,
            'quantity' => $quantite,
        ]);
        $unit_price = new \Drupal\commerce_price\Price($role_price->number, $role_price->currency_code);
        $order_item->setUnitPrice($unit_price);
        $order_item->save();
        \Drupal::logger('commande_et_paiement')->notice('Prix @role : @prix',
        array(
            '@prix' => $order_item->getUnitPrice(),
            '@role' => $role[1],

        ));  

        $line_item[$i]=$order_item;
    }

    //creation de la commande
    $entity_type_manager = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager');
    $order_storage = $entity_type_manager->getStorage('commerce_order');
    $new_order = Order::create([
      'type' => 'default',
      'store_id' => 1,
      'checkout_flow' => 'boulangerie',      
      'uid' => $user,
      'billing_profile' =>$profile,
      'order_items' =>$line_item,
      //'state' => 'draft',  
      'field_abonnement' => $nid,
      'placed' => time(),
      'field_date_livraison' =>$date_livraison->format('Y-m-d'),

    ]);

    $new_order->save();
    $new_order->set('order_number', $new_order->id());
    $new_order->save();

}
```

In the watchdog the price is good, but not in my order.
If I try to set quantity of the `order_item` just after the `setPrice` function, the quantity is OK in my order too :

```
// Set the quantity with setQuantity.
    $order_item->setQuantity(50);
```

It seems that when the order is saved the `order_item` price has been updated?

Here is my resolver class :

```
class PrixRoleResolver implements PriceResolverInterface {
    public function resolve(PurchasableEntityInterface $entity, $quantity, Context $context) {
        //kint($context);
        $current_user_id = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
        $account = User::load($current_user_id);

        if ($account->hasRole('biocoop')) {
            $role_price = $entity->get('field_prix_biocoop');
            return new Price($role_price->number, $role_price->currency_code);
        }

        if ($account->hasRole('montagne')) {
            $role_price = $entity->get('field_prix_montagne');
            return new Price($role_price->number, $role_price->currency_code);
        }

        if ($account->hasRole('vente_directe')) {
            $role_price = $entity->get('field_prix_vd');
            return new Price($role_price->number, $role_price->currency_code);
        }

        if ($account->hasRole('administrateur_boutique')) {
            //l'administrateur quand il créé une commande le site applique le prix lié au role du client

            $client=$context->getCustomer();
            $client_uid = $client->uid;
            if (!empty($client_uid))  { 
                $uid = $client_uid->getString();
                //kint($uid); 
                if (!empty($uid)) {
                    $client_user_id = $uid;
               ÷    $account = User::load($client_user_id);
                    if ($account->hasRole('biocoop')) {
                        $role_price = $entity->get('field_prix_biocoop'); 
                        return new Price($role_price->number, $role_price->currency_code);
                    }
                }
            }

        }


        return $entity->getPrice();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the price of order items in unplaced orders (i.e. carts) is recalculated regularly in Drupal 8 similar to the product pricing process in Drupal 7. If you're trying to achieve a different base price for different user roles, you likely need to implement a custom price resolver to do so.

Unfortunately, we currently have documentation handy for that, but you can look at our work in the [Drupal 8 version of Commerce Pricelist](https://github.com/mglaman/commerce_pricelist) for an example. (This is actually one of the key features of that module, so perhaps you can eventually eliminate your custom code.)

Comment: Thank's Ryan, I have already a custom price resolver, that's fine to display good price for customer according to the user role, but when I create  programmatically an order on cron_job, the function is not called...

  
I try the Commerce Pricelist, but the latest release date  is june 2015...
The module seems to have lot of bugs, can not add reference fields....

Comment: I just added the class resolver to my question.